# How to simulate blinking cursor right of input value's text when not focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I simulate a blinking cursor to the right of an input field's value-text even when it is blurred?

On focused the field gets the blinking cursor, but I want it show in both states.

How can I do this?

I thought of a `<span>` wrapping the | character and that flashes with an animation, but there can't be html ( `<span>` ) as the value or part of the value of the value attribute.

I know a quick solution would be to focused or autofocus the field, but I can't have that as on focus of the field, other things happen.

Comment: @aldanux a blinking | character to the right of the input, but the input's value is considerably smaller than the width of the input.

Comment: What "other things happen" that you're trying to prevent?

Comment: I mean... Show some code what you have tried... and would be good if you could make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you were on the right track with the idea of a span wrapping a "|" character, and animating it. If you can place that right after your input element, then you can use the general sibling selector to hide it when the input has focus (otherwise you have two cursors), and absolutely position it inside the parent element to appear on top of the input element.

So your HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="container">
<input id="input"> </input>
<span id="mock-cursor">|</span>
</div>
```

Hiding the cursor when the input has focus would be like this in CSS:

```
input:focus ~ #mock-cursor {
    display: none;
}
```

Then you would do the absolute positioning and the animation itself. It sounds like you are familiar with the animation process, so I won't go into detail on that here, but I'm linking to a CodePen demo that does this, in case you need to see some code for that as well.

http://codepen.io/rjenkins/pen/sJhHB

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `focus()` for doing that task. There is no need to use the animated character (|).